# Trouble getting countdown timer to work with Swift in UIKit

Tags: swift, xcode, timer, countdown

I'm pretty new to Swift and having a problem with getting my countdown to work, I'm currently getting an error.

1. The label I've assigned to be the countdown text isn't displaying the countdown.

Thank you in advance for any help.

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

class CountdownViewController: UIViewController {



    @IBOutlet weak var countdownLabel: UILabel!

        let futureDate: Date = {
        let future = DateComponents(
                      year: 2020,
                      month: 12,
                      day: 03,
                      hour: 09,
                      minute: 32 ,
                      second: 45
                  )
                  return Calendar.current.date(from: future)!
              }()

           var countdown: DateComponents {
                  return Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: Date(), to: futureDate)
              }



    @objc func updateTime() {
                  let countdown = self.countdown //only compute once per call
                  let days = countdown.day!
                  let hours = countdown.hour!
                  let minutes = countdown.minute!
                  let seconds = countdown.second!

           self.countdownLabel.text = String(format: "%02d:%02d:%02d:%02d", days, hours, minutes, seconds)

        }



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        func runCountdown() {
                         Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
                     }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Error:
   You get the error because you declare the variable inside of viewDidLoad(). You have to declare it outside of viewDidLoad().
2. Error:
   There the same problem exists. Declare the function updateTime() outside of viewDidLoad() and the error should no longer appear.

I hope I could help :)

Comment: Thanks Lukas! now my label isn't showing the countdown anymore, any ideas? please see edited code above.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that now the runCountdown() function is never called because you did it outside of viewDidLoad(). The runCountdown function have to be in viewDidLoad(). Everything else must be outside.

Comment: Oh okay, I've tried it again and it still isn't picking up the countdown, I've updated the code above. Thanks!

Comment: I might have an idea. You changed the name of the class, did you do the same for the ViewController in the storyboard?
It is also possible that the label is not connected properly. To check this, print it in viewDidLoad (print(countdownLabel)).

Comment: good shout, I've checked the ViewController and its the right class. I thought about the label not being connected so I checked both (print(countdown)) & (print(countdownLabel)) - the countdown prints the countdown correctly, the countdown Label prints the label properties. I'm stumped.

Comment: Is only the text of the label not displayed or the whole label?  You can check this by giving the label a background color.
If the whole label isn‘t  displayed you might have forgotten the constrains? By the way, it is a singel view App, isnt it? Or do you have a container view?

Comment: Hi Lukas, thanks for the reply. I've given it a background colour and when simulated, it shows - so it's only the tex o f the label that isn't displaying correctly. Its a single view app with a tabcontrollerView. Thanks :)

Comment: also getting this warning on (print(countdownLabel)) -  Coercion of implicitly unwrappable value of type 'UILabel?' to 'Any' does not unwrap optional

Comment: Ok, but it already worked to display the text, right? You can ignore the error, the value of countdownLabel is output anyway.

Comment: Can you print day, hour and so on. Do these variables have a value?

Comment: The label displays the text of the label and not the expected countdown timer. when (print(countdown)) is called it prints the right values. It's just now the designated label should be printed those values

Comment: I have one last idea.  Try the command: self.countdownLabel.text().    Maybe this will work.

Comment: yeah I tried that, see code above. Still no luck. :(

Comment: Does it work that the function updateTimer() is called?